# My OOP PHP method not execute

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I have file 'class_reg.php' that contains class 'Reg', and some methon 'registration' in it, it recive some input value and insert it into the database via PDO. And I have 'dbconfig.php' file, where I connect to database, include my 'class_reg.php' file and create object '$user'.  And I have some 'registration.php' file where I include 'dbconfig.php' file and try to run my method  'registration' but it not work. So here my files:

### **class_reg.php**

```
<?php
class Reg{

    public $db;

    function __construct($con){
        $this->db = $con; //$con содержит подключение к базе данных
    }

    public function registration($userName, $pass){
        try{
            $sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers ( userName, pass, fullName, email ) VALUES 
                                                    ( :userName, :pass )");

            $sql->bindparam(":userName", $userName);
            $sql->bindparam(":pass", $pass);

            $sql->execute();

            return $sql;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Error with data :". $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url){
        header("Location: $url");
    }

}

?>
```

### **dbconfig.php**

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$pass = '8169x5it';
try{
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=reg_form', $user, $pass);
}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo "POD Error :".$e->getMessage(); 
}
include_once 'class_reg.php';
$user = new Reg($con);
?>
```

### **registration.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if(isset($_POST['userName'])){
$form = $_POST;

//var_dump($_POST);

$userName = $form[ 'userName' ];
$pass = md5($form[ 'pass' ]);

if($user->registration($userName, $pass)){
    $user->redirect("all_users.php");
}else{
    echo "0";
}
}
?>
```

So, it redirect me to my file 'all_users.php' that display all users I insert to database but data not inserting to database. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong in my code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your SQL is invalid.  You're only passing 2 fields when your SQL expects 4.  The PDO handler isn't configured to throw exceptions.  Add `$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` after instantiation.

Comment: plus `bindparam` should be a capital P.

Comment: Since you're using PDO with prepared statements, I honestly don't know why you're using MD5 instead of password_hash()

Comment: Have you even tried to debug your code or just noticed "*it's not working*"?

Comment: I try password_hash but it don't work, I dont'know why..

Comment: it's your PHP version then. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: how can I debug my code? Coul you tell me plaese? I look at my data base and it's empty.

Comment: go over the comments again. Nobody upvoted my comment about `bindparam` which that should read as `bindParam`; fact not fiction. Plus, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, including exceptions, as already noted.

Comment: I got this error 'Error with data :SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 10'. Problem in my database structure.

Comment: ask Mike then below. *Moving on...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your problems have been answered in comments, but I will try to summarize and note a few additional things.

The main problem is invalid SQL as noted in the comment above by @danronmoon  You have a mismatch between number of columns specified and number of values provided.  If you are not entering full name and email values, remove these column specifications from your insert.

You also have typo when trying to use `bindParam()` as noted in comments.

The reason your see "proper" redirect behavior is two-fold:

I don't see where you have configured your PDO object instance to utilize Exception error mode, so no Exception is thrown when there is an error. Thus the Exception handler is not being triggered

Your return from the method should be:

```
return $sql->execute();
```

not

```
return $sql;
```

as `$sql` is just your PDOStatement object (assuming that your fix other problem above and `prepare` works properly).